# Indeterminate forms limits

Tags: limits

Why did $∞^∞$ is not an indeterminate form ? 
We have seven indeterminate form $$0/0 $$
$$∞/∞$$
$$0\cdot∞$$ $$∞-∞$$ $$0^0$$ $$1^{\infty}$$ $$∞^0$$ but it does not have $$∞^∞ $$why

Comment: A large number to the power of a large number is always a large number.  This is unlike how a small number divided by a small number acts which could either be small, large, or somewhere inbetween.

Answer (score 3):

Because you can definitely **determine** what it does:  it goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

So long as $a>1$ we know that $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}x^a \to \infty$ and that $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}a^x \to\infty$.

Thus we can easily predict that $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}x^x \to \infty$ as well. As such, $\infty^\infty$ is very much *determinate*.

Comment: $a>1$ for the second one.

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly with what you've written, but $\infty^\infty=\infty$ is meant to be a sorthand for the statement "for any $f,g$, if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x))^{g(x)}=\infty$"

Comment: @Randall - Ah, thanks. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

if you admit that $+\infty \times +\infty=+\infty$

$x^x=e^{lnx^x}=e^{x\ln x}$ as $x\ln x\underset{x\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty\qquad (+\infty \times +\infty)$

Thus $x^x=e^{x\ln x}\underset{x\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty$